# How do I use the HTML title attribute in a React component that has its own 'title' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, rsuite

I am using the HTML title attribute in my react application for tooltips, but I am also using rsuite Steps component, which has a title attribute.

```
<Steps.Item
     status={this.getStepStatus(0)}
     title={this.state.hideText ? : "Discovery"}
/>
```

Basically, I want to have another title="Discovery" to be the tooltip for the Step item when the screen size gets to a point where you can't see the step title any more. I am using HTML title as tooltips throughout the application so I don't really want to use something different for the sake of consistency. Does anyone know if there's a way to use the HTML title within this component? I have tried wrapping it in a span or a div but that breaks the styling of the Step.Item component.

Comment: It's completely down to the implementation of `Steps.Item` to pass the `title` prop as an attribute to whatever elements it renders, and it sounds like it doesn't do that, so I don't think you're gonna be able to do what you want using that component. @Medi react-helmet doesn't sound relevant to this question, since it is use for controlling the elements in the document head, not the title attribute of an HTML element in the document body.

Comment: Rsuite components often have a way to specify a `componentClass` that is used to render the component, where you could supply your own custom "component" that will render a title attribute, but it appears the `Steps` module does lack this feature.